# getting www to appear in address bar for site hosted on vps

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, vps

Hopeful I posted this on the right stackExchange.

I have a site hosted on a VPS with Windows Server 2008 (not R2). When I type in www.example.com it takes me to my site but the address bar only displays `http://example.com`

How do I get www to show? I have the following dns records created. Please not I am fairly new still to vps and dns records and the ones I created are from google searching.

in Forward lookup Zones I created a new zone called example.com with the following dns records

```
Name                     Type                           Data
(same as parent folder)   Start of Authority (SOA)   [2014021810],ns1.example.com.,hostmaster.example.com.
(same as parent folder)   Name Server (NS)               ns2.example.com.
(same as parent folder)   Name Server (NS)               ns1.example.com.
(same as parent folder)   Host (A)                       192.0.2.123
(same as parent folder)   Mail Exchange (MX)             [10] mail.example.com
mail                      Host (A)                       192.0.2.123
ns1                       Host (A)                       192.0.2.123
ns2                       Host (A)                       192.0.2.123
webmail                   Host (A)                       192.0.2.123
www                       Host (A)                       192.0.2.123
```

Comment: A) why do you care about `www` showing?  B) how's IIS setup?

Comment: A)Guess I just prefer it that way and when I give information to people of my site I always start with www. B)Please explain a bit more in what you mean by how is IIS setup?

Comment: [IIS... the web server I assume you're using.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)  Presumably, you have a [301 redirect in there](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect), which you'd want to remove.

Comment: I don't have HTTP Redirection installed

Comment: It might be necessary to disclose the actual domain name. See [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is giving you a `301` redirect to the non-www version when you access the `www`-prefixed version. You need to look at the IIS configuration.

Your DNS configuration is correct.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you point me in the right direction on what I need to look for?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that close experience with IIS, so I cannot tell more. Google for `IIS redirect` and you will see several articles on the subject.